# postgres offset by value not number

Tags: postgresql, subquery, offset

I have a table with at least a "name" column and an "ordinal_position" column. I wish to loop each row starting from a certain row the user inputs. Let's say the user inputs "John", and that his ordinal_position is 6 (out of a 10 total). How do I loop only the last 4 rows without using a subquery? I've tried using the "OVER()" window function but it doesn't seem to work on the offset part of the query, and that same offset only takes numbers (as far as I know) not strings.

EDIT (in response to klin):

```
INSERT INTO foo(id,name,ordinal_position) VALUES
(DEFAULT,'Peter',1),
(DEFAULT,'James',2),
(DEFAULT,'Freddy',3),
(DEFAULT,'Mark',4),
(DEFAULT,'Jack',5),
(DEFAULT,'John',6),
(DEFAULT,'Will',7),
(DEFAULT,'Robert',8),
(DEFAULT,'Dave',9),
(DEFAULT,'Michael',10);
```

so in my FOR, since the user inputed "John" I want to loop through Will-Michael. Something like the following but without a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY ordinal_position OFFSET
    (SELECT ordinal_position FROM foo WHERE name='John');
```

Comment: Provide example data at least, in form `insert into my_table values ...`

Comment: Without a subquery? It is elementary! `select t1.* from foo as t1 join foo as t2 on (t2.name = 'John' and t1.ordinal_position > t2.ordinal_position);`

Comment: Nice! I would have actually used something like that had I only the table to worry about, but I failed to explain and write out my entire query as it has many more conditions than the ones shown. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to query the table to find an `ordinal_position` for a given `name`.
However, do not use `offset`. You can do it in `where` clause, for large tables it will be much faster:

```
select *
from foo
where ordinal_position > (select ordinal_position from foo where name = 'John')
order by ordinal_position;

 id |  name   | ordinal_position 
----+---------+------------------
  7 | Will    |                7
  8 | Robert  |                8
  9 | Dave    |                9
 10 | Michael |               10
(4 rows)
```